# What is the use of keyword 'force' & this code snippet is not showing 'bats'

Tags: python, regex

This code snippet is not showing 'bats' & moreover 'eats' is showing as 'eat' in the last?
When I don't use '[force]' 7 'at' is showing?
What is the use of 'force'?

```
t="A fat cat doesn't eat oat but a rat eats bats."
mo = re.findall("[force]at", t)
print(mo)
['fat', 'cat', 'eat', 'oat', 'rat', 'eat']
```

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: at the end of the list 'bats' should be there

Comment: Add the `b` to the list of characters: `[forceb]`

Comment: "It is the Jedi's ability to recognize the Force in himself and to use it to his benefit."

Comment: What about `eats`?

Comment: `force` is not a keyword. `[abc]` means "either a or b or c", so `[force]` is "either f or o or r etc". You could use `[focer]` with the same result. As of the `s` you never told regex to match anything beyond "at"

Comment: @MattJoy No problem. May the force be with you :) <(°.°)>

Comment: How can I represent the all the alphabets in this [] instead of writing specific characters

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` assuming english alphabet case-insensitive.

Comment: Got it. But if I use this [a-z]at[a-z] then I'm only getting 2 matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of places where you can find explanation of Python regular expressions is [re module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), in your case - `[force]at` relevant part is that `[]` is

> Used to indicate a set of characters. In a set:
>
> ```
> Characters can be listed individually, e.g. [amk] will match 'a', 'm', or 'k'.
> ```

Therefore `[force]at` will match: `fat`, `oat`, `rat`, `cat`, `eat`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
import re
t="A fat cat doesn't eat oat but a rat eats bats."
mo = re.findall("\w*at\w*", t)
print(mo)
```

output:

```
['fat', 'cat', 'eat', 'oat', 'rat', 'eats', 'bats']
```

`\w*` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`* Quantifier` — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

> **[force]at**
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [force] force
>   matches a single character in the list force (case sensitive) at
>   matches the characters at literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to ask what is the use of force keyword

Comment: check my edit :)

Comment: `force` is not a keyword here. It’s just the set of characters f, o, r, c and e. You could use `cefor` or any other permutation of those 5 characters and have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/MmybH9/1). There you have an explanation for your whole regex you use. I.e. comare it to `[fc]at` to get a feeling for it.